# HoloCircularProgressBar: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: de.passsy.holocircularprogressbar.R$attr.circularProgressBarStyle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use [HoloCircularProgressBar by Pascal Welsch](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar) and it's giving me issues in Android Studio (v0.5.3, for what it's worth, it didn't give me any issues when I was using Eclipse, and I didn't change anything during migration) and I keep getting this error when it tries to inflate from the layout XML:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: de.passsy.holocircularprogressbar.R$attr.circularProgressBarStyle
            at de.passsy.holocircularprogressbar.HoloCircularProgressBar.<init>(HoloCircularProgressBar.java:218)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.mavensay.rithm.fragments.RecordVideoFragment.onCreateView(RecordVideoFragment.java:113)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
            at com.mavensay.rithm.RecordVideoV2.onStart(RecordVideoV2.java:42)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1194)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My XML Layout:

```
    ...
    <de.passsy.holocircularprogressbar.HoloCircularProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/recordingProgress"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:marker_visible="false"
        app:progress_background_color="@color/lt_grey"
        app:progress_color="@color/landingPageStartColor"
        app:thumb_visible="false" />
    ...
```

and here's the relevant code from HoloCircularProgressBar

```
/**
 * Instantiates a new holo circular progress bar.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param attrs
 *            the attrs
 */
public HoloCircularProgressBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    // line 218 vv
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.circularProgressBarStyle);
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new holo circular progress bar.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param attrs
 *            the attrs
 * @param defStyle
 *            the def style
 */
public HoloCircularProgressBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // load the styled attributes and set their properties
    final TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar,
            defStyle, 0);

    setProgressColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_progress_color, Color.CYAN));
    setProgressBackgroundColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_progress_background_color,
            Color.MAGENTA));
    setProgress(attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_progress, 0.0f));
    setMarkerProgress(attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_marker_progress, 0.0f));
    setWheelSize((int) attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_stroke_width, 10));
    mIsThumbEnabled = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_thumb_visible, true);
    mIsMarkerEnabled = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_marker_visible, true);

    mGravity = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.HoloCircularProgressBar_android_gravity, Gravity.CENTER);

    attributes.recycle();

    mThumbRadius = mCircleStrokeWidth * 2;

    updateBackgroundColor();

    updateMarkerColor();

    updateProgressColor();

    // the view has now all properties and can be drawn
    mIsInitializing = false;

}
```

Main module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply from: 'signing.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile project(':devsmartAndroid')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')

    compile project(':library')    // <-- this is HoloCircularProgressBar
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.0.0@aar"
    compile project(':rithmLibrary')

    compile files('libs/bugsense-3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/flurryAnalytics_3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/isoviewer-1.0-RC-28.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.2.2.jar')
}
```

And HoloCircularProgressBar's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

And the project's settings.gradle:

```
include ':devsmartAndroid'
include ':facebookSDK'
include ':rithmLibrary'
include ':library'    // <-- this is HoloCircularProgressBar
include ':main'
include ':rithm'
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: How are you including the library? Can you add the relevant build files to your question?

Comment: @ScottBarta added main build.gradle, HCPB's build.gradle, and the project settings.gradle. I appreciate you looking into this :)

Comment: Hmm, the build files look pretty normal. I'm not sure what the problem is.